# Do noindex pages need meta description and keywords tags?

Tags: seo, meta, noindex

When I specify a page as having `<meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>`, are the description and keywords meta tags looked at by search crawlers? Can I exclude them entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude them entirely. Meta keywords and description are not used by search engines for indexing. Meta description is only used to display information in search results, but since you don't index your page, it does not make sense to create a description.

Answer (score 0):

The `noindex` value disallows *indexing* the content of a document.

When a bot crawls this document, it can of course see everything, which includes the `meta`-`description` and `meta`-`keywords`, but it may not index this content.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what the flag does. I'm wondering since no indexing is occurring, is there any point in having keywords and descriptions?

Comment: @tomp: How could this be answered? (If you wonder about SEO potential, note that this is off-topic here.) There are so many different kinds of bots/crawlers/tools. Depending on which you care about, there can be a point in having these `meta` tags, yes.